# Remove all items from cart after checkout in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have a simple e-commerce app, and I'm trying to clear the cart after pressing the 'Proceed to checkout' button.
After pressing it I should redirect to cart and I shouldn't see any OrderItem in the cart. Also the database instance should be deleted.
How can I do?

store/models.py

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    price = models.FloatField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class OrderItem(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.quantity} of {self.item.name}"

    def get_total_item_price(self):
        return self.quantity*self.item.price

    def get_final_price(self):
        return self.get_total_item_price()


class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(OrderItem)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    ordered_date = models.DateTimeField()
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

    def get_total(self):
        total = 0
        for order_item in self.items.all():
            total += order_item.get_final_price()
        return total
```

store/views.py

```
class HomepageView(generic.ListView):
    model = Item
    template_name= 'store/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'item_list'

class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Item
    template_name='store/detail.html'

class CartView(generic.View):
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            order = Order.objects.get(user=self.request.user, ordered=False)
            context = {
                'object': order
            }
            return render(self.request, 'store/cart.html', context)
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            messages.warning(self.request, "You do not have an active order")
            return redirect("/") 

def checkout(request, user_id):
    #code to remove all items from cart

    return redirect('store:cart', user_id=user_id)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just set `order.ordered = True` in your `checkout` function, then the cart query will not be valid, thus clearing the cart, and you can keep the order in your records. I do not suggest outright deleting the object.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you're getting everything in cart by the  below query

```
order = Order.objects.get(user=self.request.user, ordered=False)
```

So, you can delete the cart using same query with `delete()` as below

```
Order.objects.get(user=self.request.user, ordered=False).delete()
```

Answer (score 1):

checkout() function after @DanielOdicho suggestion:

```
def checkout(request, pk):
    order = get_object_or_404(Order, pk=pk)
    order.ordered = True
    order.save()

    return redirect('store:cart', user_id=request.user.id)
```

It works!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).